# Navigation Bar looks larger on different page with same code

Tags: css, html, frontend

I have a navigation bar inside a few pages. It's repeated code for now.
I just want to get it up and working.
On my `home` page, it shows up bolded and slightly larger.
On my `about` page, it shows up slightly less bolded and slightly smaller.
I'm just confused as to why, they have the exact same code (copy pasted) except the href *a* tags are modified (urls are different).

Here is the html kind of summarized:

```
<body>
<Header>
    <img src="img/header.gif" alt="Dental Dynamics Logo Header" class="header_logo">
</Header>
<nav>
    <div class="toggle-nav">
        <i class="fa fa-bars menu" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>

    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="html/about.html">About Us</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="">Doctors</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="html/officeTour.html">Office Tour</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="">Sterilization Infection Control</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="">Technology</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="">Bleaching</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="">Photos</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="">Map</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="">Post Op</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="">Forms</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="">Insurance/Payment</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="">Just For Fun</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(() => {
        $('.menu').click(() => {
            $('ul').toggleClass('active');
        })
    })
</script>
```

This is the CSS to go along with it:

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,0.6), rgba(255,255,255,0.6)), url("./../img/dental_background.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.header_logo {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
nav {
    width: 100%;
}

nav ul {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}

nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
}

nav ul li a {
    font-weight: 700;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 62.5%;
    color: #0000e0;
    display: block;
    padding: 1.5em;
} 

nav ul li a:hover,
nav ul li a:focus {
    font-size: 70%;
    color: blueviolet;
    background: rgba(177, 173, 173, 0.3);
}

.toggle-nav {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0.5% 1.1%;
    text-align: left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: 150%;
    color: #0000e0;
    display: none;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .toggle-nav {
        display: block;
    }

    nav ul {
        width: 100%;
        display: block;
    }

    nav ul li {
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .active {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Any ideas as to why this is happening?
I have a header with an image tag but the size of that is remaining the same.
This is all just a bunch of HTML and CSS.
No javascript (besides the JQuery happening within the HTML file, not a fan of jquery but oh well :D )

---------------------------------- EDIT ----------------------------------
[image: Home Page Nav Bar]
[image: About Page Nav Bar]
Top pic is the `home` page nav bar, bottom is the `about` page nav bar.

It may be worth noting that the `toggle-nav` portion is related to the `link`
`<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">` in the head?

In fact, here is the `head` from the `about` page which is identical to the `home` page except for the `Title` tag.

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
<title>About Us!</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/styles.css" type="text/css">
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Do you have some screenshots ?

Comment: Yes, as Arkellys said, add screenshot and also the code of both pages (Its possible that you may have missed something descpite copy-paste)

Comment: By the way, why use the 'nav' tag? Just use a 'div'

Comment: He is right to use a "nav" tag is correct in this context, the tag provides meaning, hence semantic.

Comment: @vicgoyso that is totally right. It provides meaning so I figured why not use it!

Comment: @Arkellys I added Screenshots! Sorry, I wasn't sure if that would be overkill or not.
@AhmadBilal I can add the code if you still want, but it's pretty much exactly the same (except paths). I did add an update where it says `edit` though